# Triangulating a x-monotone polygon

Tags: computational-geometry

I am having trouble figuring out how to triangulate an x-monotone polygon. I am referencing [this article](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/Triangulation.pdf). I don't understand how to check if a vertex is an ear and if there is a diagonal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Though it's a good article, this question can quickly become obsolete if the URL changes. Please post some sample code as the main bulk of your post.

Comment: I don't have any code yet because I can't figure out the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer to the [ear cutting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation#Ear_clipping_method) which is a n^2 time algorithm. There are many simple algorithms to triangulate a simple polygons. One of the simplest n log n time algorithm consists of first splitting the simple polygon into monotone pieces and then triangulate these pieces. The splitting in that case takes n log n. In your case, as you already have the monotone piece(s) you can triangulate the x-monotone polygon easily in linear time.

A good explanation of this simple algorithm is given for example in the book [Computational Geometry](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/274s03/).

Roughly the idea is: You know that your polygon is x-monotone. Thus, you split it into its two monotone chains (upper and lower). Now you can walk along both chains and insert diagonals between the two chains without visibility check. You go along the upper chain as long as the next lower chain vertex is of smaller x-value. In case your vertex is reflex you put it on a stack, otherwise you insert a diagonal to the other side. When you take the next step on the other chain, you first insert diagonals to every vertex on the stack and then go on with this routine.

Comment: This is what I'm going to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See page 13/25, "Triangulation: Theory".  The diagram illustrates a test to see if p is the vertex on an ear.  Its neighbors are q and r.  If the line segment qr is a diagonal, then p is on an ear.

You test a line segment to see if it's a diagonal by testing if any other vertices lie on it or if any other edge line segments cross it.